# Add 3 panels to a frame in java with JSplitPane?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jsplitpane

Trying to add 3 panels i created to a frame in Java with the JSplitPane. Have tried this with 2 panels, and that worked great, but with 3 it still does not do what i want.

Have read something about making 2 JSplitPanes and put the one in the other, but that does not actually work what i would like it to do.

My code shows that there are 3 panels, but the size are all wrong.. it should be filled out.

**My code:**

```
    frame = new JFrame(); // Create a new frame
    frame.setVisible(true); // Makes it visible     
    frame.setSize(900, 500); // Sets size         
    frame.setTitle(""); // Sets title
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Sets the window on the center of the screen   

    temp_panel = new JPanel(); // Creates new JPanel
    water_panel = new JPanel(); // Creates new JPanel
    power_panel = new JPanel(); // Creates new JPanel

    temp_panel.setBackground(Color.decode("#2ecc71")); // Sets color
    water_panel.setBackground(Color.decode("#3498db")); // Sets color
    power_panel.setBackground(Color.decode("#f1c40f")); // Sets color

    temp_label = new JLabel("This is Temperature");
    water_label = new JLabel("This is Water consumption");
    power_label = new JLabel("This is Power consumption");

    // Add labels on panel
    temp_panel.add(temp_label);
    water_panel.add(water_label);
    power_panel.add(power_label); 

    JSplitPane splitPaneLeft = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
    JSplitPane splitPaneRight = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
    splitPaneLeft.setLeftComponent( temp_panel );
    splitPaneLeft.setRightComponent( water_panel );
    splitPaneRight.setLeftComponent( splitPaneLeft );
    splitPaneRight.setRightComponent( power_panel );

    splitPaneLeft.setEnabled(false);
    splitPaneLeft.setDividerSize(0);

    splitPaneRight.setEnabled(false);
    splitPaneRight.setDividerSize(0);

    // put splitPaneRight onto a single panel
    JPanel panelSplit = new JPanel();
    panelSplit.add( splitPaneRight );

    frame.add(panelSplit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

It should look like this, but just with 3 panels with 3 different colors instead of 2!

[image]

Hope someone can help

Comment: Why JSplitPane? Why not instead place your 3 JPanels into another JPanel that uses a GridLayout? Is there a specific reason that you need to use JSplitPane?

Comment: Didn't knew you could do that... will try it right away . thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to change the relative sizes of the components during runtime, don't use a JSplitPane. Instead create a container JPanel that uses GridLayout, say `new GridLayout(1, 0)` for 1 row and variable number of columns, add your three colored JPanels to the GridLayout-using JPanel, and add this then to the JFrame.

Comment: What you mean with the relative sizes... my program are going to change, but that it only the labels which will change over time.

Comment: It works now.. i had made another panel and used the GridLayout on that panel, now i got 3 rows :) thx man

Answer (score 0):

you could make one of the panels another JSplitPane, unfortunately there is no other solution for this.